# Pod to Pod communication within a Service

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes

Is it possible to send a http Rest request to another K8 Pod that belongs to the same Service in Kubernetes?

E. G.
Service name = UserService , 2 Pods (replica = 2)

```
Pod 1 --> Pod 2 //using pod ip not load balanced hostname 
Pod 2 --> Pod 1
```

The connection is over Rest `GET 1.2.3.4:7079/user/1`

The value for host + port is taken from `kubectl get ep`

Both of the pod IP's work successfully outside of the pods but when I do a `kubectl exec -it` into the pod and make the request via CURL, it returns a 404 not found for the endpoint.

**Q** What I would like to know if it is possible to make a request to another K8 Pod that is in the same Service?

**Q** Why am I able to get a successful `ping 1.2.3.4`, but not hit the Rest API?

**below is my config files**

```
 #values.yml
replicaCount: 1

 image:
  repository: "docker.hosted/app"
  tag: "0.1.0"
  pullPolicy: Always
  pullSecret: "a_secret"

service:
 name: http
 type: NodePort
 externalPort: 7079
 internalPort: 7079

ingress:
 enabled: false
```

## deployment.yml

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ template "app.fullname" . }}
  labels:
    app: {{ template "app.name" . }}
    chart: {{ .Chart.Name }}-{{ .Chart.Version | replace "+" "_" }}
    release: {{ .Release.Name }}
    heritage: {{ .Release.Service }}
spec:
  replicas: {{ .Values.replicaCount }}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: {{ template "app.name" . }}
        release: {{ .Release.Name }}
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
          image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag }}"
          imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.image.pullPolicy }}
          env:

            - name: MY_POD_IP
              valueFrom:
               fieldRef:
                fieldPath: status.podIP
            - name: MY_POD_PORT
              value: "{{ .Values.service.internalPort }}"
          ports:
            - containerPort: {{ .Values.service.internalPort }}
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /actuator/alive
              port: {{ .Values.service.internalPort }}
            initialDelaySeconds: 60
            periodSeconds: 10
            timeoutSeconds: 1
            successThreshold: 1
            failureThreshold: 3
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /actuator/ready
              port: {{ .Values.service.internalPort }}
          initialDelaySeconds: 60
          periodSeconds: 10
          timeoutSeconds: 1
          successThreshold: 1
          failureThreshold: 3
          resources:
{{ toYaml .Values.resources | indent 12 }}
    {{- if .Values.nodeSelector }}
      nodeSelector:
{{ toYaml .Values.nodeSelector | indent 8 }}
    {{- end }}
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: {{ .Values.image.pullSecret }
```

## service.yml

```
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: {{ template "app.fullname" . }}
  labels:
    app: {{ template "app.name" . }}
    chart: {{ .Chart.Name }}-{{ .Chart.Version | replace "+" "_" }}
    release: {{ .Release.Name }}
    heritage: {{ .Release.Service }}
spec:
  type: {{ .Values.service.type }}
  ports:
    - port: {{ .Values.service.externalPort }}
      targetPort: {{ .Values.service.internalPort }}
      protocol: TCP
      name: {{ .Values.service.name }}
  selector:
    app: {{ template "app.name" . }}
    release: {{ .Release.Name }}
```

## executed from master

[image: executed from k8 master]

## executed from inside a pod of the same MicroService

[image: executed from inside a pod of the same MicroService]

Comment: Fascinating, well, based solely on that output, it seems like there is something weird going on with your envoy proxy. I have zero experience with envoy, so maybe ask your question again being envoy specific -- since the question about pod-to-pod communication isn't accurate. Your question is actually pod-to-envoy which is an entirely different ball of wax

Comment: OK thanks Matthew, I have asked the question with Envoy tags here https://stackoverflow.com/q/54437129/694960, but I am not hopeful of a response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes as Mathew answered you can indeed communicate between pods in a Service with Kubernetes, the problem I was having was Istio was blocking the requests to each other.

**Solution**:
Disabling Istio injection solved this problem for me , I then enabled it after wards and load balancing continued, hopefully it can help some one in the future.

**see answer here**: [Envoy Pod to Pod communication within a Service in K8](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54437129/694960)

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to send a http Rest request to another K8 Pod that belongs to the same Service in Kubernetes?

For sure, yes, that's actually exactly why every Pod in the cluster has a cluster-wide routable address. You can programmatically ask kubernetes for the list of the Pod's "peers" by requesting the `Endpoint` object that is named the same as the `Service`, then subtract out your own Pod's IP address. It seems like you kind of knew that from `kubectl get ep`, but then you asked the question, so I thought I would be explicit that your experience wasn't an accident.

> Q Why am I able to get a successful ping 1.2.3.4, but not hit the Rest API?

We can't help you troubleshoot your app without some app logs, but the fact that you got a 404 and not "connection refused" or 504 or such means your **connectivity** worked fine, it's just the *app* that is broken.

Comment: Thanks Matthew, I will check the app logs again, but I can successfully send a Rest request to each Pod with the exact same URL only on the master host, which is leading to believe it is a config issue with ip or port on the K8 yaml side, do you know why this would work on the outside but not inside the first POD?

Comment: Then please update your question with the output of `curl -v` from the master, and then from within the cluster, because we can't guess what the reason is. It sounds a little like your SDN might not be working, but hard to know for sure

Comment: Hi @Matthew, I have added the output from the CURL request, hopefully you can help

Comment: Hi @Matthew, thanks can you share what exactly the Pod to Pod communication is named ? I would like to read the exact documentation to understand it more